# How can I set http header for vue-cli-service? (SharedArrayBuffer)

Tags: vue.js

On chrome 91:
Due to the SharedArrayBuffre Limit:
[Deprecation] SharedArrayBuffer will require cross-origin isolation as of M91, around May 2021. See https://developer.chrome.com/blog/enabling-shared-array-buffer/ for more details.

It is needed to add http-header for
'Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy' , 'require-corp'
'Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy' , 'same-origin'

I have tried:

import Vue from 'vue'
import WebGLCanvas from './WebGLCanvas'
import VueResource from 'vue-resource';

Vue.use(VueResource);
Vue.config.productionTip = false

Vue.http.headers.common['Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy'] = 'require-corp'
Vue.http.headers.common['Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy'] = 'same-origin'

It was not worked.